# Invalid MIT-Magic-Cookie on own machine with each new wifi connection

Tags: linux, arch-linux, x11, xmonad

I only recently dug into this issue enough to roughly understand the problem as one relating to the fact that X11 functions around connecting to a display 'server' of sorts.

Which leads to my problem - between home, university, and friends' places, my IP is always changing, and every time it does (to one I haven't previously had), my X11 plays up (running XMonad on X), and things don't run properly until I restart X through `startx`.

Doing xhost local:root seems to appropriately add new addresses to my xauth list, but it seems cumbersome for my multi-tab setup to have to be sacrificed just because I want to connect to a network with a dynamic IP. Is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That doesn't normally happen. Normally the cookie is asociated with your host name, and your host name doesn't change when you connect to a different network. What does the command `hostname` show? Does it correspond to what you see in `xauth list`? Does the hostname change when you connect to a different network, and if so how did you set this up? What distribution are you running?

Comment: I'm running Arch Linux x64, and my prompt info is usually <user> at localhost, but when I connect to certain networks it will become <user> at <some ip address>.

Answer (score 0):

The only two options I am aware of that may work are vnc and vpn. with a vpn you would appear to have a static IP address. With vnc your state would be preserved. ssh tunneling would hide ip address issues from X11 but it would still not survive a ip address change. The only reputable advice I have seen regarding changing IP addresses with X11 is don't.